# Unable to Upload a file using dojo 1.9

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, dojo

As I am trying to upload my profile pic using dojox Uploader,I am unable to upload a file using form with methods post or put(as I can update my pic).Below I have added my part of the function,

```
    request.post(url, {
              data: {
              data:domForm.toObject("profileForm"),  //complete form
              attachment:dijit.byId("attachment")._files[0].name // attachment
              },
              handleAs : "json",
              timeout: 2000,
            headers: {
                        'userId' : userId,
                        'companyId' : companyId,
                        'token' : token,
                         "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data",
                        'Accept': 'application/json' 
            }
```

my HTML part,

```
    <form id="profileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

                <input name="attachment" multiple="false" type="file" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Uploader" label="Select Some Files" id="attachment" />
                <input type="button" class="submit" value="submit" id="profilebtnId" onclick="changeProfilePic();" /> 
    </form>
```

the Java code:

```
   @Path(UserRESTOperations.PROFILE_PIC)
    @POST //@PUT
    @Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response setUserProfilePic(@PathParam(RestPathConstants.ID_PARAM) Integer userId,
            @Context HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

I am able hit the API but not able pass the content(request) to the backend (java).Sorry for my grammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and ended up using `FormData`.

```
var attachment = dijit.byId('attachment').inputNode.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('attachment', attachment);

request.post(url, {
    data: formData
    , handleAs: 'json'
    , headers: {
        Accept: 'application/javascript, application/json'
        , 'Content-Type': false
    }
});
```